# Why extensions cannot add stored properties

Tags: swift

Quoting the Swift Programming Language Guide :

> Extensions can add new computed properties, but **they cannot add stored properties**, or add property observers to existing properties.

Why is that ? What's the technical or logical reason behind this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple words

> Because properties need storage, adding properties would change the memory structure of the class

Comment: Where did you get the quote from ?

Comment: But first of all compiler compute the value of computed properties then all other stored properties and conputed properties get memory